# Liquid textfield width

Tags: css, width, textfield, liquid-layout

I have this fairly simple form:

```
<form action="...">
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="input-text" value="" name="text" />
        <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

The form is sitting inside a fixed-width div (specified in ems).

I want the textfield and button to be a single row, but the textfield width is inconsistent across browsers even when I specify its `size` attribute. Not wanting to specify exact widths (especially for the button) I was wondering if it was possible to give the textfield a liquid width? I want the textfield to stretch so that both it and the button can fit on a single line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah `length` is for character count, not width.

You want the text box to fill all available space short of what the button takes up? This is doable with a table (but I consistently get booed on Stack Overflow for suggesting tables). Let's say for the sake of argument you use DIVs with display:table, but just for simplicity I'll illustrate with actual table markup.

```
<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=100%>
  <tr>
      <td><input type="text" style="width:100%"></td>
      <td style="width:0"><input type="submit"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The width 0 on the button cell might seem odd, but table cells take their widths only as suggestions. It'll stretch to fit the content no matter how skinny you make it.

Comment: I should add though, that it's usually best not to micromanage HTML/CSS. If it were me, just giving the text box some fixed width in ems would be good enough. If you designer _insists_ that the text box and button come flush to the right edge, maybe you need a new designer?

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, though I used divs styled with "display: table", etc.  For the inputs though, is it possible to style them with "display: table-cell" directly instead of wrapping them in a td? I never got that method to work, but am attracted to it since it would mean less divs.

Comment: It may not be tabular data but it's a practical solution to a recurrent problem the current versions of HTML and CSS can't solve properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep the default submit button styles its width will vary from one browser to the next. This also means that the text field's width you seek is a variable.

- FF: 47px + 3px border
- Chrome: 45px + 2px border
- IE8: 63px + 8px padding + 3px border
- IE7: 61px + 2px border

There is no elegant way to do it, but you have the following options:

- Use tables (Google is using tables for its search box).
- Style both the input field and submit button (Not recommended).
- Use a script (Not recommended).