# Expand textfield width to fit input as typing

Tags: javascript, html, textfield

How can I get a textfield that expands it's width to accommodate the width of input while typing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Liquid textfield width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201621/liquid-textfield-width)

Comment: I'll just leave this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends what browsers are you trying to target. New browsers probably support some way of doing this only via CSS, but I doubt IE6 has such a functionality.

So if you need legacy browser support, then I suggest sticking with JavaScript.

Comment: "Probably"? You mean to say "CSS is probably the solution to any scripting needs"? As I see it, CSS is for presentation not behaviour. The OP's need is strictly in script land.

Comment: @ChristianSciberras the original question before editing was if it is possible to do this without JavaScript ...

Comment: Ah, I see. Excuse my prejudice. Nowadays it's all too common to find people expecting magic out of raw CSS.

Answer (score -1):

With CSS just set the `width` to `auto`.

Comment: Of course it won't work. An input box is different from a span or div, hence why auto width won't work. Perhaps messing with appearance CSS attrib might help, but it's a huge hack.

Comment: @amiawizard you should also consider the width of any container element where this textfield is placed.