# CSS - dynamic length text input field and submit button in one row

Tags: html, css

I have:

```
<div>
    <input id="input" type="text" />
    <button id="submit">submit</button>
</div>
```

which gives me this
[image]

If I expand the main panel by dragging it with the mouse cursor the width the new space is empty:

[image]

I want that the `<input type="text" />` fills the whole horizontal new space but that the submit button remains in the same row.

I tired to use `<input style="width:100%" type="text"/>` but then it fills the whole row and the submit button appears in the next row:

[image]

I also tried a table as mentioned in that thread:
[Liquid textfield width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201621/liquid-textfield-width)

The result was that it works "a little bit" the submit button overlaps the input text and a certain space on the right always remains empty:
[image]

Can somebody help me with an code idea for fill the whole space except the (static) size of the submit button.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "table" method you linked to will work, but you're missing one crucial property on your input elements:  box-sizing.

http://cssdeck.com/labs/sbffl3l2

```html
<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar"><input type="text"></div>
  <div class="bar"><input type="submit"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.foo {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.bar {
  display: table-cell;
}

.bar:first-child, input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
}

input {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* this is the key */
}
```

Prefixes may be required:  http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do this:

```
<input type="text" style="width:calc(100%- widthofbuttoninpixels);" />
```

It's not advisable to do inline styles though.

Edit: Make sure you also define a fixed width for the button

Comment: Defining a fixed width on elements with text is asking for trouble (what happens when the button contains different lengths of text? this could be a multi-lingual site).  The `calc()` function is not well supported on mobile devices, which can be disastrous if not accounted for.

Answer (score 0):

Why not give width of 70% to input and 20% to button?